# Docker volumn path in windows

Tags: docker

I am relatively new to docker. I want to use a database with volume to persist. I am in windows 10.

I want to check where the volumns are created in my machine.

When i run the command

```
C:\Users\satul>docker volume inspect 368984d12c3525d8752d249347cfd563afb46c847e1c109afa9785bf54b89701 [
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2018-06-25T22:43:29Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": null,
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/368984d12c3525d8752d249347cfd563afb46c847e1c109afa9785bf54b89701/_data",
        "Name": "368984d12c3525d8752d249347cfd563afb46c847e1c109afa9785bf54b89701",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    } ]
```

Since this is a windows box, i donot have folder /var/lib/docker/volumes/. Where exactly is the volumn folder in windows so that i can backit up if required.

Comment: Please see if this [link](https://blog.sixeyed.com/docker-volumes-on-windows-the-case-of-the-g-drive/) helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should not back up volumes by backing up /var/lib/docker/volumes directory. Instead you should use command (it will create the backup in your current working directory):

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from container-name -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu tar cvf /backup/backup_name.tar /mount/point/inside/container
```

Eg. for Docker registry the command looks like this:

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from registry -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu tar cvf /backup/registry_backup.tar /var/lib/registry
```

And to restore the backup you should use command:

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from container-name -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu bash -c "cd /mount/point/inside/container && tar xvf /backup/registry_backup.tar --strip number_of_leading_directory_components_in_mount_point_path"
```

Eg. to restore backup of Docker registry:

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from registry -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu bash -c "cd /var/lib/registry && tar xvf /backup/registry_backup.tar --strip 3"
```

Answer (score -1):

Usually `/var/lib/docker` is mounted on C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual hard disks. You can check it out by looking at your docker settings.

A docker `volume` is just a directory on your host machine with all your container data, so you could use any methods you wish to backup your data.You can see more about docker volumes in [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)

[See also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43182885/9381897)