# In which folder is data of volumes in Docker Windows stored?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-volume, docker-desktop

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43181654/locating-data-volumes-in-docker-desktop-windows) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55474693/docker-for-windows-accessing-named-volume-mounts) questions. None of them answers my question.

I have checked here:  `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual hard disks.`

and here: `C:\ProgramData` as described [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sysadmin/containerization/working-windows-containers-docker-save-data/),

and I have not seen anything.

**My question:** When I run docker volume inspect I see that the mount path is `/var/lib/docker/volumes` where can I access that folder? Is it possible?

Why do I want to know this? I am just trying to understand docker better.

I am using windows 10 and Docker version 19.03.5.

Comment: This seems like it's an exact duplicate of the first question you link to; what are you asking that's different?  As a general rule you're not supposed to directly access named volume content from the host, and on non-Linux hosts I'd expect that path to be in a VM, and the answers to that question describe the standard ways to manage that data or put it somewhere accessible.

Answer (score 1):

I got same problem before. Here is what I found now, there will be a "wsl" folder under /mnt

in WSL, go to path:

```
/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/docker/
```

u can find all ur images, containers and volumes data