# Jenkins Startup fails on AWS ECS due to secrets-manager-credentials-provider-plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

I'm using the [AWS Secrets Manager Credentials Provider](https://github.com/jenkinsci/aws-secrets-manager-credentials-provider-plugin) plugin and it seems to be causing Jenkins to fail on startup.

I've followed the troubleshooting steps [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/aws-secrets-manager-credentials-provider-plugin/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting/index.md) with no luck, the last thing I did was split out the IAM perms.

I am running the Jenkins/Jenkins:lts docker image, on AWS ECS, and describing my stack using AWS CDK. i installed the plugin using `/usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh` from the docker image.

When I run the same docker image on an EC2 server startup is succesful but via ECS i get this error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.jenkins.plugins.credentials.secretsmanager.AwsSecretSource.reveal(AwsSecretSource.java:35)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.SecretSourceResolver$ConfigurationContextStringLookup.lambda$lookup$ad236547$1(SecretSourceResolver.java:141)
    at io.vavr.CheckedFunction0.lambda$unchecked$52349c75$1(CheckedFunction0.java:247)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.SecretSourceResolver$ConfigurationContextStringLookup.lambda$lookup$0(SecretSourceResolver.java:141)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1632)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.SecretSourceResolver$ConfigurationContextStringLookup.lookup(SecretSourceResolver.java:143)
    at org.apache.commons.text.lookup.InterpolatorStringLookup.lookup(InterpolatorStringLookup.java:144)
    at org.apache.commons.text.StringSubstitutor.resolveVariable(StringSubstitutor.java:1067)
    at org.apache.commons.text.StringSubstitutor.substitute(StringSubstitutor.java:1433)
    at org.apache.commons.text.StringSubstitutor.substitute(StringSubstitutor.java:1308)
    at org.apache.commons.text.StringSubstitutor.replaceIn(StringSubstitutor.java:1019)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.SecretSourceResolver.resolve(SecretSourceResolver.java:109)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.PrimitiveConfigurator.configure(PrimitiveConfigurator.java:44)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.DataBoundConfigurator.tryConstructor(DataBoundConfigurator.java:159)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.DataBoundConfigurator.instance(DataBoundConfigurator.java:76)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.BaseConfigurator.configure(BaseConfigurator.java:267)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.DataBoundConfigurator.configure(DataBoundConfigurator.java:82)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.HeteroDescribableConfigurator.lambda$doConfigure$16668e2$1(HeteroDescribableConfigurator.java:277)
    at io.vavr.CheckedFunction0.lambda$unchecked$52349c75$1(CheckedFunction0.java:247)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.HeteroDescribableConfigurator.doConfigure(HeteroDescribableConfigurator.java:277)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.HeteroDescribableConfigurator.lambda$configure$2(HeteroDescribableConfigurator.java:86)
    at io.vavr.control.Option.map(Option.java:392)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.HeteroDescribableConfigurator.lambda$configure$3(HeteroDescribableConfigurator.java:86)
    at io.vavr.Tuple2.apply(Tuple2.java:238)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.HeteroDescribableConfigurator.configure(HeteroDescribableConfigurator.java:83)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.HeteroDescribableConfigurator.configure(HeteroDescribableConfigurator.java:55)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.DataBoundConfigurator.tryConstructor(DataBoundConfigurator.java:151)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.DataBoundConfigurator.instance(DataBoundConfigurator.java:76)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.BaseConfigurator.configure(BaseConfigurator.java:267)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.DataBoundConfigurator.check(DataBoundConfigurator.java:100)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.BaseConfigurator.configure(BaseConfigurator.java:344)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.BaseConfigurator.check(BaseConfigurator.java:287)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.BaseConfigurator.configure(BaseConfigurator.java:351)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.BaseConfigurator.check(BaseConfigurator.java:287)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.lambda$checkWith$8(ConfigurationAsCode.java:777)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.invokeWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:713)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.checkWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:777)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.configureWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:762)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.configureWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:638)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.configure(ConfigurationAsCode.java:307)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.init(ConfigurationAsCode.java:299)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:104)
Caused: java.lang.Error
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:110)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder$TaskImpl.run(TaskMethodFinder.java:175)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1129)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:282)
    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:49)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:1162)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:960)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:86)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:82)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:295)
Caused: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:312)
```

I have also submitted an issue.
https://github.com/jenkinsci/aws-secrets-manager-credentials-provider-plugin/issues/117#issue-938932773

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: In the [like from your question](https://github.com/jenkinsci/aws-secrets-manager-credentials-provider-plugin/issues/117) is a simpler solution: To use `AWS_REGION`. I was using `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` which isn't working.

Here's my simplified solution.

```
# install aws cli
ARG AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
ARG AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
ARG AWS_REGION
ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID} \
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY} \
    AWS_REGION=${AWS_REGION}
RUN wget "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -O "awscliv2.zip" \
    && unzip -q awscliv2.zip \
    && ./aws/install \
    && rm awscliv2.zip
```

for completeness here's my make build command

```
build:
    echo -e $(shell getent group docker | cut -d: -f3)
    docker build -t $(PROJ):$(VERSION) --build-arg DOCKER_GID=$(shell getent group docker | cut -d: -f3) \
    --build-arg AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(shell aws configure get aws_access_key_id --profile=default) \
    --build-arg AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(shell aws configure get aws_secret_access_key --profile=default) \
    --build-arg AWS_REGION=$(shell aws configure get region --profile=default) \
    -f Dockerfile .
```

**OLD ANSWER:**

Looks like Hudson uses credentials and config from `~/.aws`
Problem with Jenkins and docker is that $JENKINS_HOME is a volume ([as I learned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56065245/how-to-access-var-jenkins-home-in-docker)), not a folder.
You can't create folders in there from Dockerfile.

Luckily you can [change the location of those configs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/file-location.html).

Here's part of my Dockerfile that solved the issue:

```
ARG AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
ARG AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
ARG AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
ENV AWS_CONFIG_FOLDER=/opt/.aws
ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID} \
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY} \
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION} \
    AWS_CONFIG_FILE=$AWS_CONFIG_FOLDER/config \
    AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE=$AWS_CONFIG_FOLDER/credentials
RUN wget "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -O "awscliv2.zip" \
    && unzip -q awscliv2.zip \
    && ./aws/install \
    && rm awscliv2.zip \
    && mkdir $AWS_CONFIG_FOLDER \
    && aws --profile default configure set aws_access_key_id "$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" \
    && aws --profile default configure set aws_secret_access_key "$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" \
    && aws --profile default configure set region "$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" \
    && chown -R jenkins:jenkins $AWS_CONFIG_FOLDER
```

Comment: Adding AWS credentials to the container image (`ENV`) is a serious security issue. Please don't do that, especially if you publish those container images.