# Cannot access docker volume's mountpoint with Docker for Windows

Tags: docker, docker-machine

All I want to is accessing docker volume's `Mountpoint` in terminal.

```
PS C:\> docker volume create myvol
myvol
PS C:\> docker volume inspect myvol
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2019-12-04T13:41:02Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {},
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/myvol/_data",
        "Name": "myvol",
        "Options": {},
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

Now I want to access to **Mountpoint path** `/var/lib/docker/volumes/myvol/_data`.

```
PS C:\> docker-machine ssh default
docker@default:~$ cd /var/lib/docker
docker@default:/var/lib/docker$ sudo su
root@default:/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker# cd volumes
root@default:/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes# ls -al
total 32
drwx------    2 root     root          4096 Dec  4 13:25 .
drwx--x--x   15 root     root          4096 Dec  4 13:27 ..
-rw-------    1 root     root         32768 Dec  4 13:27 metadata.db
```

It seems `Mountpoint` path doesn't exist. So I thought it is because the volume is empty, so I tried again after generate some files on that volume, However the result is same - There is no `myvol` directory in `/var/lib/docker/volumes`.  Is it normal? Even if the dir doesn't exist I can store data permanently with this volume. Is it normal behavior or something I missed?

Comment: Hi Juntae, have you mounted the volume to your container? not sure about docker-machine, but with docker you would run something like `docker run -v myvol:/path/to/mount myimage`

Comment: `/var/lib/docker/volumes/myvol/_data` is the location of the volume data on your host machine

Comment: @ClemensKaserer Yes, I created some files to the volume. And it is host machine. it's not bind mounts but data volume.

Comment: You shouldn’t be trying to directly access that `/var/lib/docker` subdirectory at all.  If accessing the files from your host is important, a bind mount is a better choice than a named volume.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64418064/8074003

I could find in `\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\volumes\`  several directories, one directory for each one of the data volumes.

Also is posible to be found in `\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\volumes` it depends on the docker engine version.