# How to access container's mounted directory on windows10?

Tags: windows, docker, hyper-v

1.I started a container with a simple command:   `docker run <image_id>` 
2.made some changes to files inside the container 
3.Executed docker commit
4.Then realized the changes weren't commited to the new image 
5.docker inspect shows a mounted directory for whatever reason:

```
  "Mounts": [
       {
           "Name": "8ced..",
           "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/8ced../_data",
           "Destination": "/mydata",
           "Driver": "local",
           "Mode": "",
           "RW": true
       }
   ],
```

6.So .. on windows where is this source location? I use Hyper-V **without** wsl2 
7.I have read through these advices : [Locating data volumes in Docker Desktop (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43181654/locating-data-volumes-in-docker-desktop-windows).
 Non of them worked, all of the mentioned locations are empty in my case.
8. How can I read/write into this mounted directory directly by hand?

Comment: Is using [docker cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) to move files and folders on/off an option? I know it doesn't answer the "modify directly by hand" question.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with enough details to demonstrate the problem.  (Ideally in Dockerfile syntax; `docker commit` isn't really reproducible and I'd advise against using it.)