# On Windows, where are the files of my CMS running with Docker?

Tags: docker, prestashop

I already found a command line to get a path of the files corresponding to my CMS (Prestashop) that runs with Docker, i.e:

```
docker exec -it <mycontainer> bash
```

But, it brings me to:

```
root@4c3cae74d5b1:/var/www/html#
```

Which looks like a Linux path. So, do you know how to know where the files are situated on my Windows file system ?

Thanks a lot !

Aymeric

Answer (score 0):

If you have not otherwise specified, the files are only inside the one container filesystem, not at all on your host filesystem. The files are in your Windows file system only if you have used bind mounts when running your container and mapped host files/directories to container volume mounts.

In general Docker files can exist in three places:

1. layered container filesystem (default)
2. volumes (persistent volumes in your Docker host, volumes can be shared between multiple containers running on the same host)
3. bind mounts (files or directories in your Docker host filesystem)

You did not provide the actual `docker run` command you have used to run your Prestashop. This would reveal what option your setup is. More info on Dockker volumes can be found here: https://docs.docker.com/storage/

Which ever way you have stored the volume, you can use `docker cp` command to copy data between your container and host operating system.

Technically of course also the container filesystems and volumes are stored on your host disk but are not meant to be accessible directly. It is not recommended to access them directly and different versions of Docker have different restrictions. Some info on where to find it on Docker for Windows can be found from answers to this question: [Locating data volumes in Docker Desktop (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43181654/locating-data-volumes-in-docker-desktop-windows)