# How can I create a VS Code Dev Container given an existing volume?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, vscode-devcontainer

My dev Container is gone, but the volume is still there. How can I create a new container with this volume as /workspaces mount? In the volume is a .devcontainer.json, which could be used to recreate the container. But how?

Comment: so 1. Locate&restore it ([win](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43181654/592355), [mac-like](https://forums.docker.com/t/host-path-of-volume/12277)) 2. Once you open vs code in a folder with a devcontainer.json, a dialog should offer you to start that.. (Alternatively <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P Devcon...</kbd>) (??)

Comment: well, I'm using a remote docker-host. So it is not so easy to locate and restore. Also I think there must be a possibility to create a container with an existing image!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a local folder with a `.devcontainer/devcontainer.json` file and [use a named volume](https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/improve-performance#_use-a-named-volume-for-your-entire-source-tree):

```json
"workspaceMount": "source=your-volume-name-here,target=/workspace,type=volume",
"workspaceFolder": "/workspace",
```

Then run `Dev Containers: Open Folder in Container...` to connect to the container.

If it's a workspace volume that contains multiple repos, then use the `File > Open Folder...` command to open the cloned repository in the container.