# Why `docker inspect <volume>` shows non-existing path?

Tags: docker

I have no volumes:

```
$ docker volume list
DRIVER    VOLUME NAME
```

I start container with volume named `FooBarVolume`:

```
$ docker run --rm -it -v 'FooBarVolume:/zzz' alpine sh
```

I write into that volume and exit from container back to docker host:

```
/ # touch /zzz/test.txt
/ # ls -l /zzz/
total 0
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Dec  4 13:29 test.txt
/ # exit
```

I see the volume created:

```
$ docker volume list
DRIVER    VOLUME NAME
local     FooBarVolume

$ docker inspect FooBarVolume
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2023-12-04T13:29:15Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": null,
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/FooBarVolume/_data",
        "Name": "FooBarVolume",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

But where is that volume?

```
$ sudo ls -la /var/lib/docker/volumes/FooBarVolume/
ls: cannot access '/var/lib/docker/volumes/FooBarVolume/': No such file or directory

$ sudo find / -type d -name FooBarVolume
###    ^ this finds nothing
```

But contents of the volume are still accessible:

```
$ docker run --rm -it -v 'FooBarVolume:/zzz' alpine ls -l /zzz
total 0
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Dec  4 13:29 test.txt
```

What's the trick? Why `docker inspect <volume>` shows non-existing path? WHERE my volume is stored?

I use Windows 11 Home Single Language 64 bit (version 22H2) with `wsl2` (version 2.0.9.0) and Docker-desktop 4.21.1 (114176), Docker engine 24.0.2.

Comment: In general you shouldn't expect to be able to directly access the contents of named volumes (even on native Linux, where that `docker inspect` path happens to work).  If you need to directly access the files, use a bind mount instead.

Answer (score 0):

Even though `docker inspect <VolumeName>` says the volume is located on path `/var/lib/docker/volumes/...`, there are no `/var/lib/docker/` on my system at all (since I use Docker-desktop for Windows, not "normal" Linux docker). While searching for details on this question, I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76799344/1688077), and the suspicion was confirmed: data volumes of Docker desktop for Windows running with `wsl` are located in totally different place, which is pseudo-network-drive `\\wsl.localhost\`.

So my `FooBarVolume` is stored not at `/var/lib/docker/volumes/FooBarVolume/_data`, but at `\\wsl.localhost\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\volumes`: (see Windows explorer screenshot below).

[image: Windows explorer screenshot]