# Is named docker Volume stored on host machine

Tags: docker, jenkins, devops, docker-machine, persistent-volumes

i am new to devops specially docker, i have created a docker image to config Jenkins inside a docker container to make the data persistent i have used docker volume, i am using the following command:

docker run -p 8080:8080 -d jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home

this command is running jenkins through docker and storing data in jenkins_home named volume

can i find where this Jenkins data is located on the host machine and i can access the jenkins data or the volume data is stored in container itself

is there a way to store jenkins data on host drive using volumes?

i am using windows 10

i want the data on the host machine
thanks :)

Comment: Well for windows its not quite that easy. I would assume you are using docker desktop on windows 10?. If so, you have two options. If you are using wsl all your docker desktop data/configs/mini linux vm stuff will be stored under: \\wsl$ path on windows, you just need to find the right wsl instance and click it through. You get the location for inside the wsl instance with docker volume inspect command under mountpoint data. If you are using hyper v then /var/lib/docker is usually mounted in C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual hard disks.

Comment: You can also check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43181654/locating-data-volumes-in-docker-desktop-windows question, i think it will answer you in more detail than i can summarize here.

Comment: Hey, is there a way to map jenkins data to be stored on host machine using volume, if yes. how to do that

Comment: I dont use jenkins on my regular basis, but i have found online resource: https://rangle.io/blog/running-jenkins-and-persisting-state-locally-using-docker-2 which does what you need and more.

But to sum it up:

docker container run -d \
    -p [YOUR PORT]:8080 \
    -v [YOUR VOLUME]:/var/jenkins_home \
    --name jenkins-local \
    jenkins/jenkins:lts
If you were wondering what the arguments stand for, here is what each means:

-d: detached mode
-v: attach volume
-p: assign port target
—name: name of the container

Comment: You shouldn't normally expect to directly access data in a Docker named volume, though it is in practice in a predictable place and an accessible format.  Consider using a Docker [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) `-v /host/path:/container/path` instead, if you need to directly access the data from the host.